# Set Node.js to $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu, deployment, webserver

I am studying RoR and I am setting this virtual machine to "deploy" RoR and I got stuck in the Node.js installation.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I followed this step of this guide:

http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html

> Since Rails 3.1, a JavaScript runtime has been needed for development on Ubuntu Linux (it is not needed for Mac OS X or Windows). For
>   development on Linux Ubuntu, it is best to install the Node.js
>   server-side JavaScript environment:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install nodejs`
>
> and set it in your $PATH.

What does it mean, "set to my $PATH"?

I've been searching for it on google in the last couple of hours and all solutions are different, for different problems and I get no simple answer for that. Can you give a little light here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't have to worry about that, the `apt-get install` command will do that for you. 
It adds the path to the nodejs process (usually `/usr/bin/node`) to the global $PATH variable. This ensures that when you type `node` in your terminal it will start the nodejs process.

If for some weird reason you cannot start it, you'll have to manually add the path to your node installation to the $PATH. You can do this by editing your `~/.bashrc` file and adding:

```
PATH=/usr/bin/node:$PATH
```

Comment: Which assumes the OP is using bash. ;-)

Comment: you also need to reload bash.rc source ~/.bashrc

Comment: ~/.bashrc command isn't working in ubuntu. How can I edit this

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node
this is my node path. If I change the path to /usr/bin/node 
then my problem was solved?

Answer (score 17):

I've been trying to install `npm` and it has complained about `node` not being in the path. Funnily enough, `nodejs` was, but `node` wasn't. I ended up solving the problem thus:

```sh
$ cd /usr/bin/
$ sudo ln -s nodejs node
```

...which symlinks `node` to `nodejs`. Now `npm` installs without complaints.

Comment: This was required in UBuntu 16.04 after installing with apt-get. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 16.04, did this, fixed the node issue but now npm isn't recognized anymore

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which shell you are running, the answer may be different, but a good starting place might be http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm

And http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645

Comment: In order for your answer to be ideal, you should summarize the main points of those links because they may be dead in the future. Thanks for the links, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted Ubuntu after the install. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Could you specify the Ubuntu version you're using?