# /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory , c++

Tags: c++, node.js, less

i am writing some functions on c++ for compiler less to css.

i installed `nodejs`, `less`.
i created a less file `test.less`

```
@color: red;
a{color:@color;}
```

when i run command on terminal:

```
lessc test.less test.css
```

it created a files css with name is `test.css`, but when i run this command via c++, it return a error. please help me. this is my c++ function:

```
std::string shell_exec( std::string cmd )
{
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (pipe == NULL)
    {
        return result;
    }
   char buffer[128];
   while(!feof(pipe))
   {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        {
            result += buffer;
        }
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
} 

shell_exec("lessc test.less test.css");
```

i got a error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

`/usr/bin/node` is existed.

[image]
 [image]
[image]

## ================ UPDATE: Fixed==================

Thank you @Bass Jobsen , @Lightness Races in Orbit

i fixed by add absolute path to lessc and nodejs

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/lessc test.less test.css");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20890795/560648

Comment: I don't really believe that it works from terminal but not from within your C++ program.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is true.

Comment: You should possible read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245252/can-i-open-bash-from-a-popen-stream

Answer (score 1):

From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620

> The advantage of #!/usr/bin/env python is that it will use whatever
>   python executable appears first in the user's $PATH.

So you should add node to the `$PATH` of the user that runs your script, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210246/1596547

Notice that i can not compile your code, but i can when using the following code:

```
int main()
{
std::string r =  shell_exec("lessc test.less test.css");
}
```

Probably also use `using namespace std` and `string` instead of `std:string`.