# Cannot run node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, docker, maven, ubuntu, npm

I execute `mvn clean install` inside a docker container from image `maven:3-alpine` to build the application. In the pom.xml I make use of the `frontend-maven-plugin` because I need to install `node` and `npm` and then run `npm install` to build the frontend (angular).

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <nodeVersion>v12.16.1</nodeVersion>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
              <installDirectory>./</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>ng build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Node and npm will be installed correctly but when it runs `npm install` it returns an error: `Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProject/node/node" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProject"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]`

If I enter into the container (docker exec) and try to run manually npm install it gives me again the same error. When I check if node is correctly installed then I see the file `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProject/node/node` is there but when I try to run node from inside the /node directory myself, let's say `node -v` it says me again `No such file or directory`. I don't understand why it is happening, because node is there!! The current user has also the right to execute this file.

I did some search about the problem, some people say that installing node on ubuntu in this way is not the correct way but that happens only in my container. If I try the same on my local machine (it is also an ubuntu) then node works.

Comment: Does it have the execute bit set in the file mode?

Comment: It looks like that:
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      46228688 Jun  4 10:40 node
drwxr-xr-x    3 108      112           4096 Jun  3 13:37 node_modules
-rwxr--r--    1 108      112            893 Jun  3 13:37 npm
-rwxr--r--    1 108      112            464 Jun  3 13:37 npm.cmd
And I try to run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `node -v` on it's own it's trying to find node on your PATH. Installing via maven in this manner will not do so for you

[Check out one of these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203335/set-node-js-to-path), for how to do that on Linux.

If your user does not have permissions to do so, which I suspect may be the case given you are running in jenkins, you can instead run the commands required using the full or relative path to the node and npm binaries.

e.g. if you have a file `test.js` in directory `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProject`, in that directory could run either:

```
./node/node test.js
```

or

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProject/node/node
```

---

Aside: a better solution to using Maven to install NPM & Node in your CI environment would be to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), Docker images, or for Jenkins [use the Node.js plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/).

Comment: As I said, I also tried to start the same container on my host and tried to enter it with `docker exec` and tried to execute node with root user. It doesn't work either with absolute nor relative path. I also know that there are also other ways to do it, but I still need to understand what the problem is here. The whole thing is working on my host with ubuntu, why it is not working with an alpine docker image?!

Comment: Ah sorry that wasn't clear on your question, you just said "but when I try to run manually let's say node -v" - thought you were trying to execute that command on it's own

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited my question to be more clear. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. Apparently alpine is not working well with nodejs binary. There seem to be some workarounds thou https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/633.